# How to use a UICollectionViewCell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a cell originally created as a `UICollectionViewCell` but I want to be able to reuse it in a `UITableView`. Would I simply have to reimplement it in the form of a UITableView or is there any alternative?

The `UITableView` needs to present the exact same cell as well, but it can't because of the lack of cross-compatibility. My original cell is declared as such and uses a NIB file for the UI layout:

```
class originalCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //parent view that nests several other views
    @IBOutlet weak var viewBackground: UIView! 

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, I'd recommend creating a subclass of `UIView` and move the subviews that are currently in your collection view cell into this subclass. Then use this subview as the contentView of both your collection view cell and table view cell.

Comment: I updated the question to provide a little more detail about the structure of the code. Would appreciate actual code snippets on how to accomplish what you mentioned for your solution